# Migrate MySiteHost site collection from one Sharepoint 2019 farm to another

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019

We would like a backup of the MySites user personal sites in testing environment from production one. Both environments are of Sharepoint 2019 version. Both have UPS and Managed Metadata service configured.
Can anyone provide detailed steps to achieve the following:

1. Copying personal sites (like "/personal/") of few users from one farm to another
2. Copying entire My Sites of all users from one farm to another.

I haven't been able to find the right steps to achieve it so far.

Regards

Comment: I don't think there is any official guides out there. You should be able to backup some of the users sites using the PowerShell cmdlt 'backup-spsite' and then restore them in the other farm. For moving all the sites, you should be able to backup the whole content database and restore it to the other farms mysite webapplication.